# Fourier transform of $\cos(n\omega t)$

Tags: fourier-transform

My question is probably very stupid, but I've been strugling for a while on it now...

In need to find the Fourier transform of $1+\cos^3(2\pi ft)$.

I wrote that :
$$\cos^3(2\pi ft)=\frac{\cos(6\pi ft)+3\cos(2\pi ft)}{4}$$
And so I have:
$$\delta(f) +\frac 18 \bigg[\delta(f-3f_0)+\delta(f-3f_0)\bigg] +\frac 38 \bigg[\delta(f-f_0)+\delta(f-f_0)\bigg]$$

So, on my spectrum, I should have a dirac at $0$, a smaller one at $f_0$ and a smaller at $3f_0$...

But when I process it with matlab (using fast fourier transform), I get this :

[image]

(With a frequency of $10\textrm{ kHz}$).

So the dirac I thought would be at $3f_0$ is in fact at $\frac{f_0}{2}$. What am I missing ?

Comment: What is the value of $f_0$, also what is the (simulated) sampling frequency $F_s$ and what is the FFT length $N$ ?

Comment: Welcome to DSP.SE! What sampling frequency are you using? It looks like 20kHz.

Comment: Since you expect a harmonic at 30 kHz, you need to sample at more than 60 kHz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take a look at the first half of your expansion; $cos(6\pi f_{0} t)$

The Fourier transform for this would be

\begin{equation}
   X_{c}(j\Omega) = \pi \delta(\Omega - 6\pi f_{0}) +  \pi \delta(\Omega + 6\pi f_{0})
\end{equation}

For your Fourier transform to be correct, we need that 
\begin{equation}
     6\pi f_{0} < \pi f_{s} 
\end{equation}

This means that your sampling rate must be high enough to avoid aliasing. Are you sure that your $f_{0} < f_{s}/2?$

To me it looks like this is the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you so much everyone!

I am really not confident in my mathematics skills and so I was focusing on the Fourier transform, but as you all guessed, the problem was my sampling frequency way too small (I was using 25kHz). With 60kHz it works like a charm.
Still feels like an idiot though ;-)

Thank you !

PS : To sum up if anyone was facing the same kind of problem

The theoric part was wright. We have :
$$\delta(f) +\frac 18 \bigg[\delta(f-3f_0)+\delta(f-3f_0)\bigg] +\frac 38 \bigg[\delta(f-f_0)+\delta(f-f_0)\bigg]$$

The problem was with my simulation: I forgot to check if my sampling frequency was meeting the Nyquist-Shannon criteria ($Fs > 2F_{max}$).

So, with this code :

```
Fs = 7e4;            % Sampling frequency
T = 1/Fs;             % Sampling period
L = 100000;             % Length of signal
t = (0:L-1)*T;        % Time vector
fm = 10e3;

X = 1+(cos(2*pi*fm*t)).^3;
%X = 1 + 0.25*cos(3*2*pi*10000*t)+(3/4)*cos(2*pi*10000*t);
Y = abs(fft(X));

f = 0:Fs/L:Fs/2;
plot(f,Y(1:L/2+1))
xlabel('f (Hz)')
ylabel('|P1(f)|')
```

We get the expected result:
[image]